# liferay + bonita integration plugin make error

Tags: liferay, bonita

> I had install liferay(liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558) and bonitaSoft(BonitaBPMCommunity-6.0.1-Tomcat-6.0.35). I want to connect liferay and bonita with BonitaBPM Integration.lpkg([here](http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/26827133)) plugin. But i have a error!! No connection.

Comment: BonitaUtilException: java.util.Collections$EmptyMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap

Comment: exactly the same as this same time question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30140756. Also, I'm not aware of the bonita versions, but Liferay is available in GA4 - please try the latest of both environments. Chances are that the issue might be fixed already

Comment: i know that they have more later version. I use BonitaBPM Integration.lpkg plugin for connect two web app, which wrote for older versions. If you know how connect them please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked on liferay & Bonita integration so far.

But came across this steps may be helpful

http://www.bonitalife.org/documents/107425/111991/Step+by+step+BonitaLife+Example/7069f955-9ee1-4c16-b019-c3a8cb06b476